# Are angels spirits?

Tags: angels, spirit

> *John 4:24 (KJV)* 
>   **God is a Spirit**: and they that worship him must
>   worship him in spirit and in truth.

The Gospel of John tells us that God is a Spirit. What about the angels? According to the Bible, what are angels?  Are they also spirits or something else?

Comment: Both [NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%204:24&version=NIV) and [NASB](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%204:24&version=NASB) lack the non-definitive article 'a'; they simply say "God is spirit" with the NASB giving a note "or *Spirit*". I think if you focus your question more on the text and what it means you will get more meaningful answers on the hermeneutics site. Or maybe I am having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: To me, saying "a spirit" implies an individual kind of thing. Saying only "spirit" implies a description of being. It is the difference between definitions 1 and 4 found [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spirit).

Comment: @fredsbend The question is actually not on God, but on angels. With the knowledge that God is spirit, and since angels are not human, it simply assumes that angels might also be spirits.

Comment: Well, the differences in these translations leaves me confused. I'm eager to see what answers you get. Perhaps I will post on hermeneutics to get to the bottom of that.

Comment: [Psalm 104:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+104&version=KJV) is interesting. It is quoted in Hebrews.

Comment: [Related](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4530/how-are-angels-and-humans-different?rq=1), but only has one mediocre answer.

Comment: Related issue is asked [here again in Hermeneutics.SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5743).

Comment: @Mawia Here are some links that might be helpful. The first link exhausts the nature of Angels as far as Scripture goes.  The 2nd is an except of *Theology and Sanity* by Frank Sheed. His definition of *spirit* is the best Christian philosophical presentation you will find in modern times. The third is a discussion by Dr. Peter Kreeft at Boston College about St. Thomas Aquinas' Angelic theology.
(1)http://scripturecatholic.com/angels.html  
(2) http://payingattentiontothesky.com/2012/12/21/spirit-by-frank-sheed/
(3) http://www.peterkreeft.com/audio/10_aquinas-angels.htm

Comment: Some Christians think that angels are not merely spirits; as such this question is too broad/primarily opinion-based.  See [Do angels possess 1) a body, soul and spirit, 2) a soul and spirit or 3) just a spirit?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/42408/21576)

Answer (score 4):

When Abraham's servant went to find a wife for Isaac (Gen 24), he had angelic influence (no mention of the angel physically accompanying him).  The angels who came to escort Lot and his family out of town were corporeal as they ate dinner (Gen 19:3).  In Matthew 2:13, an angel appears to Joseph in a dream.  However, an angel was able to physically kick Peter in the side to wake him up (Acts 12:7).  The author of Hebrews says we may entertain angels (13:2) which suggests a physical form.

It would seem angels have the ability to assume both corporeal and non corporeal forms as they see fit, suggesting they have both physical and spirit attributes.

Answer (score 1):

From the Cathecism of the Catholic Church:

> CCC 328 The existence of the spiritual, non-corporeal beings that
>   Sacred Scripture usually calls "angels" is a truth of faith. The
>   witness of Scripture is as clear as the unanimity of Tradition.
>
> CCC 329 St. Augustine says: "'Angel' is the name of their office, not
>   of their nature. If you seek the name of their nature, it is 'spirit';
>   if you seek the name of their office, it is 'angel': from what they
>   are, 'spirit', from what they do, 'angel.'" With their whole beings
>   the angels are servants and messengers of God. Because they "always
>   behold the face of my Father who is in heaven" they are the "mighty
>   ones who do his word, hearkening to the voice of his word".
>
> CCC 330 As purely spiritual creatures angels have intelligence and
>   will: they are personal and immortal creatures, surpassing in
>   perfection all visible creatures, as the splendor of their glory bears
>   witness.

It should be noted that the ability for people to interact and see angels constitutes a miracle. Being a miracle, one cannot produce conclusions of the angelic nature from such events.